# Vector Navigation and equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

So I am taking a grade 12 physics online course and I am getting stuck on the Vector Navigation equations as there isn't much explanation in my course.

The following text is found in my online course. This is the only explanation that is given. This is the first time I am encountering such a problem in my course.:

```
    Vector Navigation: Component Method, Example 1

Use the following sample as a guide... 



  An airplane heading at 450 km/h, 30° north of east, encounters a 75 km/h     
wind blowing towards a direction 50° west of north.  What is the resultant 
velocity of the airplane relative to the ground?

Step 1)  Draw each vector

Resolve each vector into components.


Vwind x = 75 cos40 = - 57.4 km/h
Vwind y = 75 sin 40 = + 48.2 km/h

Vplane x = 450 cos 30 = + 389.7 km/h
Vplane y = 450 sin 30 = + 225 km/h


Step 2) Add the component vectors...to find resultant

X-Direction:

Vector Equation: vRx = vwind-x + vplane-x

Scalar Equation: vRx = vplane-x - vwind-x

vRx = 332.3 km/h

Y-Direction:

Vector Equation: vRy = vwind-y + vplane-y

Scalar Equation: vRy = vplane-y + vwind-y

vRy = 273.2 km/h

Resultant:  

Vector Equation: vR = vRx + vRy

Scalar Equation: vR = sqrt [vRx2 + vRy2]

vR = sqrt [332.32 + 273.22]

vR = 430 km/h

Step 3) Find the resultant direction.
tan θ = opp/adj

tan θ = vRy/vRx



θ = 39˚ N of E


The resultant velocity of the airplane is 430 km/h, 39° N of E
```

This is not a "How do I solve this problem" question. All I need is an explanation of the two different equations in step 2, namely:

```
Vector Equation: vRx = vwind-x + vplane-x

Scalar Equation: vRx = vplane-x - vwind-x
```

Can someone explain the difference between the two equations and how they are related? Why is the Scalar equation used and not the Vector equation?

Comment: This is a great example of a terrible explanation! I don't have time to fix everything that's poor, ambiguous and misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I have guessed the direction of the wind speed as it does not appear in your question.

The speed quoted for the plane is speed of the plane relative to the air $v_{pa}$.
The wind speed is the speed of the air relative to the ground $v_{ag}$.
You need to find the speed of the plane relative to the ground $v_{pg}$.

The first thing is to draw a vector diagram.

[image]

You can then put your component values on the diagram which should help you with deciphering the equations in step 2 but remember that I have guessed a direction for the wind.

By drawing the diagram you might also notice that in this case it might be easier to use the cosine and sine rules.

Comment: Yes i do realize that it is easier to use the cosine and sine rules but i have to use this method for certain questions. So my question is specifically about the vector and scalar equations used in step 2. How are they related and which one is used and why?

Comment: In the solution that you have provided the components (red and green in the diagram) are found and added together to form a right angled triangle.  The Pythagoras and the tan function are used to generate the answers.

Comment: As i commented before i'm not asking how to solve the equation. I'm asking what the differences are between the two equations which i highlighted at the end of the question.